# Sql Query for an ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following report I need to generate . I am new to SSRS.

```
   Number of Stores with      June   July  Aug
     0 sales                   12      34   32
     1 to 9 Sales              12      34   45
     10+ sales                 15      45   54
```

The tables I have are as follows :

```
Store : 
YEAR MONTH StoreName 
2013  10      ABC
2013  10      DEF
2013  09      JKL 
2013  06      FGH


Store Sales : (Contains only stores whose sales are > 0)
YEAR MONTH StoreName NumberOfSales
2013  10     ABC          3
2013  09     JKH          14
2013  10     FRH           9
```

I am not really sure what I need to do to get the report in the above format ?
I can write a query for sales in a single month , but how do I write a query  to 
get the report for all 3 months ? Or is there a better way to do these reports using ssrs ?

If you can direct me on what to do it will be great ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up your query like this:

```
SELECT Year, Month, (CASE
  WHEN NumberOfSales = 0 THEN '0 Sales'
  WHEN NumberOfSales BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN '1-9 Sales'
  WHEN NumberOfSales > 9 THEN '10+ Sales' END) [SaleGroup]
FROM FactStoreSales
```

Then you basically want to go into SSRS and just throw it into a table with the month in the columns and the group in the rows and let it pivot the data itself rather than trying to do that in SQL.

Comment: Hey David, Thanks . Could you please tell me what I need to put in the data section of the matrix ? Also, I cannot get the '0 Sales' from this table, I need to do a select storename from Stores except select storename from StoreSales in order to get Stores with 0 sales . Is there a way I can integrate this into my query ?

Comment: @Courage That's getting a little more complicated now for the 0 sales. Essentially you have to build a data set that's a cross join for every combination of stores and numbers then do a left join against the sales fact with an isnull for the count to replace null with 0. Passing that to your report you use a sum of the count(*) records against sales (ensuring your null records come back with 0 and not 1 through testing) to get the report you want.